# Traduction de certains termes de l'analyse mathématique quantique

Tags: traduction, terminologie, mathématiques

Je travaille avec des notions purement mathématiques ces derniers temps et voudrais savoir comment on traduit :

1. [Time-scale calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-scale_calculus)
2. [Forward/backward difference operator](http://mat.iitm.ac.in/home/sryedida/public_html/caimna/interpolation/d-oper.html)
3. conditions for disconjugacy

Il m'est impossible de trouver exactement d'autres articles en français qui citent ces opérateurs.

Comment: Partiellement, pour 2 [ici](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff%C3%A9rence_finie) et 3, [là](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_par_conjugaison).

Comment: Merci. mais pour (3), ce sera la "condition de conjugaison" ou la "condition de disconjugaison" ? Le terme de disconjugaison je le vois plus utilisé dans la médecine oculaire (les yeux qui louchent), mais j'ai pu aussi le retrouver dans un article mathématique [ici](https://books.google.bi/books?id=PSjfdWxB5sUC&pg=PA214&lpg=PA214&dq=disconjugaison&source=bl&ots=XfH4KJ0XlB&sig=LufZa5ULOFkOLF_tC1-PlywY9gM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eJLcVLavN8X1UMbkgNgI&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=disconjugaison&f=false) mais je ne sais si c'est la même signification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voici des liens intéressants de la banque de données terminologiques et linguistiques du gouvernement du Canada:

> [**time scale difference**](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?=fra&i=&index=alt&srchtxt=TIME%20SCALE%20DIFFERENCE): différence entre échelles de temps
>
> *Différence entre les indications lues au même instant sur deux échelles de temps*
>
> [**calculus**](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=alt&srchtxt=Calculus): calcul infinitésimal
>
> *Partie des mathématiques qui comprend le calcul différentiel et le calcul intégral.*
>
> [**forward differencing**](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=alt&srchtxt=FORWARD%20DIFFERENCING): différentiation vers l'avant
>
> *Méthode d'extrapolation dans le temps, dans les modèles de prévision numérique, qui obtient des valeurs au pas de temps suivant uniquement
>   à partir des valeurs du pas de temps actuel, sans utiliser les valeurs
>   de pas antérieurs [...]*
>
> [**backward differencing**](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=alt&srchtxt=BACKWARD%20DIFFERENCING): rétrodifférentiation
>
> *Méthode d'approximation d'une dérivée n'utilisant que l'information connue aux valeurs de la variable indépendante qui sont antérieures
>   (espace ou temps) à celle pour laquelle on calcule la dérivée.*
>
> [ [*TERMIUM Plus®*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra), la banque de données terminologiques et
>   linguistiques du gouvernement du Canada ]